# Visual studio 2019 xamarin ios project, meta data become null when running the program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I had a xamarin IOS project which was developed by visual studio 2015. Recently i converted it to visual studio 2019 and updated the latest xamarin(16.2.0.95).

But when i am navigating to another page and come back, some null exception errors happen.

The error is ->
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

This happen because of some metadata variables become null when come back from page.

I will give some examples as follow

ex 01:

`uIView.Layer.BorderWidth = new nfloat(Element.BorderWidth);`

In above code, "Element" is a variable from MetaData in visual studio. 
`public TElement Element { get; }`

This "Element" variable become null when navigate back from page.

ex 02 :

`var toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;`

In above code, "Control" is a variable from MetaData in visual studio. 
`public TNativeView Control { get;}`

This "Element" variable become null when navigate back from page.

These kind of variable (meta data) in visual studio platform become null when operating the application. ofcouse i can do null check to handle this. but my project is very large and if i put null check for all over the code, some features will not execute.

Why this happen? do we have a solution for that? please help me.

Comment: Hey Dilan! It seems like you are having issues with Custom Renderers if I'm not wrong. Could you share an example of one of those custom renderers and the corresponding implementation file?